# Flash AS3 class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I'm new to Flash and I'm currently following a tutorial about login and registration.

The tutorial that I followed has an external AS file just like this :

[image]

where I type the name of the class in the space given. So far, when I run the program, it gives me the correct output.

Now here comes my problem. I've made some modifications to the way it references(?) the class, which in this case, I export the class just like this in the symbols properties. And now, the code won't work and I've been trying to figure this out for about 5 hours already and I can't seem to get it done.

Here's the image of me adding the class in the symbols properties :

[image]

And here is my `login` class :

```
package {

    /*
        always extend a class using movieclip instead of sprite when using flash.
    */

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.text.*;

    /*
        create our class
    */

    public class login extends MovieClip {

        public function login(): void {

            /*
                buttonMode gives the submit button a rollover
            */

            login_button.buttonMode = true;

            /*
                what this says is that when our button is pressed, the checkLogin function will run
            */

            login_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, checkLogin);

            /*
                set the initial textfield values
            */

            username.text = "";
            password.text = "";

        }

        public function checkLogin(e: MouseEvent): void {

            /*
                check fields before sending request to php
            */

            if (username.text == "" || password.text == "") {

                /*
                    if username or password fields are empty set error messages
                */

                if (username.text == "") {
                    username.text = "Enter your username";
                    trace(success);
                }

                if (password.text == "") {
                    password.text = "Enter your password";
                }

            } else {

                /*
                    init function to process login
                */
                processLogin();

            }

        }

        public function processLogin(): void {

            /*
                variables that we send to the php file
            */

            var phpVars: URLVariables = new URLVariables();

            /*
                we create a URLRequest  variable. This gets the php file path.
            */

            var phpFileRequest: URLRequest = new URLRequest("php/controlpanel.php");

            /*
                this allows us to use the post function in php
            */

            phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            /*
                attach the php variables to the URLRequest
            */

            phpFileRequest.data = phpVars;

            /*
                create a new loader to load and send our urlrequest
            */

            var phpLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
            phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);

            /*
                now lets create the variables to send to the php file
            */

            phpVars.systemCall = "checkLogin";
            phpVars.username = username.text;
            phpVars.password = password.text;

            /*
                this will start the communication between flash and php
            */

            phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);

        }

        public function showResult(event: Event): void {

            /*

                this autosizes the text field

                ***** You will need to import flash's text classes. You can do this by adding: 

                import flash.text.*;

                ...to your list of import statements 

            */

            result_text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

            /*
                this gets the output and displays it in the result text field
            */

            result_text.text = "" + event.target.data.systemResult;
            trace(success);

        }
    }
}
```

**Edit :**

Here is the picture where the base class just disappears :

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: To get that working, you have to add an instance of your `login` class, manually by adding it directly to the stage or by code using for example : `var login_form:login = new login(); addChild(login_form);` ...

Comment: Thank you, I will try that now.

EDIT: Okay now another problem arose, because when I enter the base class in the Export Actionscript Panel, the flash.display.MovieClip disappears even though I pressed "ok".

Comment: This may be obvious to some how do I put it to stage or where do I put the instance? I've read a different topic here regarding adding an instance to the stage but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: You have just to drag it from the library and drop it to the stage.

Comment: Thank you! But this problem arises. The base class in the symbols properties keeps disappearing even though I've added flash.display.MovieClip more than 10 times already. I will add a screenshot

Comment: That's not a problem as your class is extending the `flash.display.MovieClip` class : `class Login extends MovieClip`.

Comment: I get these errors :(
C:\wamp\www\Login.as, Line 27 1120: Access of undefined property login_button. I've checked the instance name of the button and variables but they're all correct.

Comment: That button and those text fields should be a part of your login MovieClip.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by making the button and the text fields part of the movie clip?  But I will look for the answers. Thank you so much for the help, very much appreciated.

Comment: What I meant is that you should put those objects (button + text fields) inside your login MovieClip.

Comment: Is it in the properties? What I did was just create a text field and button inside the stage and gave it the instance names just like the names in the code. Or do I do something more than that? I've researched about it through the keywords "adding buttons or text fields in a movie clip" but I can't seem to find the correct answer.

Comment: Hi, I will put make another topic regarding a different question. Cheers.